# Mysql table allowing same column name twice and showing both columns in a table

Tags: mysql

We have created a table with some columns ,and if we trying  to alter the table its allowing us to add same column twice.

Please let us know why mysql is allowing duplicate column name in a same table

Example :

```
create table test
(
name varchar(100),
id bigint(20)
)

alter table test add column name varchar(100)
```

Comment: SQLFiddle says this is not allowed in mySQL 5.6 and you'll get the error `Duplicate column name 'name'`. Perhaps you are doing this to tables in different schemas? Or you have a very old version of mysql which has some sort of bug? (To test, go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and enter `create table test
(
name varchar(100),
id bigint(20)
);
alter table test add column name varchar(100);` ). I don't know why you would even be trying to do this anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is mysql allowing duplicate column names

Why? it's a defect in MySQL. Recent versions don't allow it.

It doesn't serve any purpose. Don't do it. Don't try to create tables with duplicate column names.

The bug has been fixed for a long time. Upgrade your server to a recent version.

Comment: Thaks for your reply